# $.ajax Chamando duas vezes

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com Vue.JS e Jquery.
A chamada está sendo feita assim no Vue:

```js
methods: {
        efetuarLogin: function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: JSON.stringify(this.Usuario),
                dataType: 'application/json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/login',
                complete:function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                    console.log(jqXHR+' - '+textStatus);
                }
            });
            
        }
    },
```

A chamada é feita duas vezes. Um dos retorno tem o resultado 204 (No Content).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não será o pre-flight do CORS? Vê se a primeira não é `OPTIONS` e a segunda `POST`.

Comment: Olá Sergio. Como verifico? Pelo verbo do cabeçalho?